# Is there a "natural" topology on powersets?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let's say a topology ***T*** on a set ***X*** is *natural* if the definition of ***T*** refers to properties of (or relationships on) the members of ***X***, and *artificial* otherwise. For example, the order topology on the set of real numbers is natural, while the discrete topology is artificial.

Suppose ***X*** is the powerset of some set ***Y***. We know some things about ***X***, such as that some members of ***X*** are subsets of other members of ***X***. This defines an order on the members of ***X*** in terms of the subset relationship. But the order is not linear so it does not define an order topology on ***X***.

I haven't found a topology on powersets that I would call natural. Is there one?

Comment: *Cofinite topology*: the proper closed sets are exactly finite sets.

Comment: Have you seen [this part of the powerset Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Topologization_of_power_set)?

Comment: @LeonidKovalev The cofinite topology on what? $X$ or the $\mathscr{P}(X)$. You can define the cofinite topology on $\mathscr{P}(X)$, but it does not really require use anything about $X$. MikeC wants a topology on $\mathscr{P}(X)$ that uses some property of $X$.

Comment: Perhaps instead of "natural" I should have said "induced". That sounds more precise -- but I don't know how to define "induced"!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Natural* is far from well-defined. For example, I don’t see why the discrete topology on $\Bbb R$ is any less natural than the order topology; one just happens to make use of less of the structure of $\Bbb R$ than the other.

That said, the [Alexandrov topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) on $\wp(X)$ seems pretty natural:

$$\tau=\left\{\mathscr{U}\subseteq\wp(X):\forall A,B\subseteq X\big(B\supseteq A\in\mathscr{U}\to B\in\mathscr{U}\big)\right\}\;.$$

In other words, the open sets are the upper sets in the partial order $\langle\wp(X),\subseteq\rangle$.

Comment: Yes, a topology defined in terms of the partial order is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott can we embed $(X,\mathcal{T})$ in $( \wp(X), \tau)$ ? For a given topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ Is there exists a topology $\mathcal {T'}$ on $\wp(X)$ so that we can embed $(X,\mathcal{T})$  in $(\wp(X) ,\mathcal {T'})$ ?

Comment: @M.A.: Yes, though it’s customary to embed it in $\wp^*(X)$, the family of non-empty subsets of $X$. For each finite $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}\subseteq\mathscr{T}$ let $$B(U_1,\ldots,U_n)=\left\{A\in\wp^*(X):A\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^n U_k\text{ and }A\cap U_k\ne \varnothing\text{ for }k=1,\ldots,n\right\}\;;$$ the family of all such sets $B(U_1,\ldots,U_n)$ is a base for a topology on $\wp^*(X)$, and $X$ embeds in this via the map $x\mapsto\{x\}$.

Comment: Do you think this topology is the same as the product topology on $2^X$ that Alex Becker mentioned?

Comment: @ziggurism: (Very belatedly seeing and answering this:) $X\in\mathscr{U}$ for each non-empty $\mathscr{U}\in\tau$, so $\mathscr{U}\cap\mathscr{V}\ne\varnothing$ whenever $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ are non-empty open sets in this topology. $\langle\wp(X),\tau\rangle$ is therefore [hyperconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space) and hence connected, whereas the product topology is totally disconnected.

Answer (score 12):

Note that $\mathcal P(X)$ is in some sense "naturally" equivalent to (and certainly in bijection with) the product space $\prod\limits_{x\in X}\{0,1\}$, since we can identify a subset $S\subseteq X$ with the element of the product space that has a $1$ in the $x$ place if $x\in S$ and a $0$ in the $x$ term otherwise. For example, the set $\{1,3\}\subseteq \{1,2,3\}$ would be identified with the element $(1,0,1)\in \prod\limits_{i=1}^3 \{0,1\}$. Using this, we can give $\mathcal P(X)$ the product topology, taking the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$.

However, this may not be what you're looking for, since it depends only on the underlying set $X$ and not on its topology.

Comment: "Natural" very much depends on context. The product topology of discrete spaces described in this answer is natural in descriptive set theory, even if the factors (or exponents) carry a topology, other than the discrete one. (For example in the context of determinacy, where products of the form $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ are common for large uncountable cardinals $\kappa$, or in the context of Borel equivalence relations, where one favors Polish topologies.)

Comment: Do you think this topology is the same as the Alexandrov topology that Brian M Scott mentioned?

Answer (score 6):

Your question is vague. You want a topology on $\mathscr{P}(X)$ that uses some property of $X$. If $X$ is any arbitrary set, you don't exactly know if $X$ satisfies any particular property.

However, there is a possible topology you can put on $\mathscr{P}(X)$ if $X$ is a topological space. I am not entirely sure that this is what you are looking for since a topology on $X$ is not a property of $X$, although often times a property of $X$ (such order as mentioned) can be used to define topologies.

Anyway, suppose $X$ has a topology. You can define the topological space generated by the sub basis

$\{K \in \mathscr{P}(X) : K \subseteq U\}$

$\{K \in \mathscr{P}(X) : K \cap U \neq \emptyset\}$

where $U$ ranges over all open subsets of $X$.

This is something artificial I made up, but if you replace $\mathscr{P}(X)$ with the set of all compact subset of a topological space $X$, then you obtain the Vietoris topology of the set of all compact subsets of a topological space $X$. The Vietoris Topology is actually a useful topology.

Comment: In [E. Michael, TOPOLOGIES ON SPACES OF SUBSETS](http://imgur.com/lpwTB1i) says that, the topologies on $\mathcal{P}^* (X)=\mathcal{A}(X)$ generated by $\{K \in \mathscr{P}(X) : K \subseteq U\}$ and $\{K \in \mathscr{P}(X) : K \cap U \neq \emptyset\}
$ are admissible with respect to the generating topology on $X$. what does _they are admissible with respect to the generating topology on $X$_ means?

Answer (score 1):

What about the following: A set $S\subset P(X)$ is open if for any $x\in S$ it also contains all $y\subset x$.

Comment: I wonder if this is the same as the Alexandrov topology mentioned by Brian M. Scott. It's not obvious to me one way or the other.

Comment: @MikeC: If I understand it correctly, in the example of Brian M. Scott for every set in $S$ all the *supersets* are also in $S$. Which if I'm not mistaken would mean the open sets in that topology are exactly the complements of the open sets in my example. However from the link I gather that the term "Alexandrov topology" is more general, and I think my example should also be one.

Answer (score 0):

The question may be  more relevant to your motivation  if you suppose $Y$ is a topological space and you ask for a "reasonable" topology on the power set of $Y$. This is quite tricky  but there are topologies on the family of closed subsets, or of open subsets, see for example

R. Brown and A.M. Abd-Allah,  ``A compact-open topology on partial
maps  with open domain'', *J. London Math Soc.* (2) 21 (1980)
480-486.

The idea is to use the Sierpinski space $S= \{0,1\}$ in which $1$ is open but not closed. Then the set $\mathcal O(Y)$ of open sets of $Y$ is given by a corresponding set  $\mathcal{CO}(Y)$   of characteristic maps $Y \to S$; this set can be given the compact-open topology. This topology is non-Hausdorff of course.